# How to deserialize multiple object within an object?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have the following JSON which I'm trying to deserialize.

```
"objects": {
    "1612": {
      "id": 1612
    },
    "1626": {
        "id": 1626
    }
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize this into a list ideally but I haven't had any luck so far.

I've tried the following:

```
public List<Object> objects { get; set; }

public Dictionary<string, Team> objects { get; set; }
```

I know that ideally the JSON should be inside an array [], but it isn't.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your json does not represent a list/array.  Its single property "objects" that is a _dictionary_ of string|object

Comment: If these can be arbitrarily many objects, it's going to be atrociously inefficient if serialized into an actual object (or `dynamic`), since properties weren't built to scale like that. Your best bet is probably to use a `JsonTextReader` explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON does not contain any collections, so a list/array would not be appropriate.

You should have a parent object with one property `objects`:

```
public class RootObject
{
    // I dont know what Team is but I assume it has the 'id' property
    public Dictionary<string, Team> Objects { get; set; }
}
```

If you are using Json.NET then the deserialization would be:

```
var rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(someJson);
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NT1axd)

Comment: @SergiuTripon if your Json is valid then I can [guarantee this works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NT1axd).  Your json in your post is not currently valid because it is not contained in a body (i.e `{ }`)

Comment: I should have mentioned that the JSON provided is part of a bigger JSON so it won't be in string type, so I can't deserialize it. I'm already deserializing the main JSON and then I need to interpret this objects part of it.

Comment: @SergiuTripon well then you need to include a [MCVE] with your post.  Otherwise we cannot answer your question.